# How did Nova create the globes in Earth From Space?

Tags: imagery, satellite, globe

[image]

Nova recently aired [Earth From Space](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/space/earth-from-space.html) on PBS.  (I highly recommend it.)  Also found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqojtGWIsww) on youtube.

> Produced in extensive consultation with NASA scientists, NOVA takes
>   data from earth-observing satellites and transforms it into dazzling
>   visual sequences, each one exposing the intricate and surprising web
>   of forces that sustains life on earth.

Does anyone know what tools and processes they used to "transform" and display satellite imagery on a global scale?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't view that video from Canada but based on the screen shot I believe something like that could be rendered in [Pov-Ray](http://www.povray.org/). 
A while back I asked a question about [how to generate a high resolution rendering of the globe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10591/how-can-i-generate-a-high-resolution-rendering-of-the-globe/10607#10607) and @scw suggested I try Pov-Ray.

Using [this guide](http://www.imagico.de/pov/earth_scene.php) I was able to create custom globes with a combination of my own inputs and, real time cloud imagery and global imagery from NASA.  It is relatively easy to tweak atmospheric effects, glow and lightning effects, add imagery and a lot more. Technically, you could render the globe at slightly different position to generate high resolution frames for a globe rotation animation.

Here are some of my attempts:

[image]

Parameters of the globe were defined in Pov-Ray (Including position of light, intensity, shadow, etc.) The only 2 external inputs are [real time cloud map](http://xplanet.sourceforge.net/clouds.php) by xplanetclouds and global imagery by NASA:
[image]
[image]

Here is another globe using [ETOPO1 global image from the National Geophysical Data Center](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/) with a custom Ontario overlay. I think I also added countries outlines to this one:

[image]

Comment: +1 Whether or not that's how NOVA did it, you present some fine examples.